# How to convert a regex to golang regex flavor which does not support backreference?

Tags: regex, go, backreference

As I searched in Google, golang's regexp uses RE2 syntax which does not support backreference (`\1`).

I have a simple regex `([^aeiouy])\1`, while I am porting a C# library to golang that replace "cutting" to "cut".

The only bit I did not finish is that regex `([^aeiouy])\1`.

How can I get a workable variation of that regex? I do not know regex a lot.

Comment: What does 'that lemma "cutting" to "cut".' mean? Also, I believe that you will have to resort to string methods, maybe together with regex.

Comment: `([^aeiouy])\1` matches `tt` in the string `cutting`. He wants to remove the second part.

Comment: I need change "cutting" to "cut" only using regex, because the whole pipeline do like such.

Comment: it like change "CCing" to "C"   the "C" equal to "([^aeiouy])\1".

Comment: replace ("([^aeiouy])\1ing","$1")

Comment: There is no alternative in RE2 syntax. Use normal string operation to do it.

Comment: There's no way to translate that particular regex. We might come up with a different solution if you tell us what exactly you're trying to achieve with that pattern though.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question, it seems like the need is to find any occurrence of "ing", where the two characters preceding the "ing" are equal.

A partial solution would be:

```
 func needsCut(s string) bool {
    ix := strings.Index(s, "ing")
    /* if the "ing" has less than two characters in fron of it, we can't do any cutting */
    if ix < 2 { 
        return false
    }

    return s[ix-1] == s[ix-2]
}
```

To see this in action: http://play.golang.org/p/bCodqVgDEz

Comment: fmt.Printf("%s can be cut: %v\n", v, needsCut(v)) // change last code line